# Twig extension issues

Tags: theming, 8

I'm trying to write a simple twig extension to render a menu inside twig template files.

I created a custom module for this purpose. It's folder structure looks like this:

```
-modules
--MenuRender
---src
----MenuRenderExtension.php
--menurender.info.yml
--menurender.services.yml
```

The `*.info` file is a standard file, the `*.services` files looks like this:

```
services:
  menurender.twig_extension:
    class: Drupal\MenuRender\MenuRenderExtension
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

And the `MenuRenderExtension` class is as follows:

```
namespace Drupal\MenuRender;

class MenuRenderExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

  public function getName() {
    return 'MODULE.twig_extension';
  }

  /**
   * @return array
   */
  public function getFunctions() {
    return [
      new \Twig_SimpleFunction('renderMenu', [$this, 'renderMenu'])
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Provides function to programmatically rendering a menu
   *
   * @param String $menu_name
   *   The machine configuration id of the menu to render
   */
  public function renderMenu($menu_name) {
    // 50+ lines so i cut this part as it's mostly clean PHP
  }

}
```

I am constantly getting this error msg in apache's error log

***Service 'menurender.twig_extension' for consumer 'twig' does not implement Twig_ExtensionInterface***

Any one have a clue ?
p.s. new to drupal8

Comment: Your module name should not be camel case, but should instead be mymodule. Your namespace needs to reflect that, too. It should likely live under a folder in `src` called `TwigExtension`, too. See: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/twig_blocks/tree/src/Twig/RenderBlock.php?h=8.x-1.x

Comment: PS I think what you are trying to achieve has been done, in some form, here: https://www.drupal.org/project/simplify_menu

Comment: @Kevin Wow you're right! It works! Wasted 2h because of such a stupid thing. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'll add it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your module name should not be camel case, but should instead be mymodule (not MenuRender). Your namespace needs to reflect that, too. It should likely live under a folder in src called `TwigExtension`, and your module name in the namespace should match the directory (i.e. `Drupal\mymodule`, not `Drupal\MyModule`).

[Here is a module that uses TwigExtension for comparison.](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/twig_blocks/tree/src/Twig/RenderBlock.php?h=8.x-1.x)

What's likely happening is the application is unable to locate certain things due to the file naming and namespacing.

Comment: This did it for me, sort of. All of our classes in an old module were named with lowercase like the module. The classes themselves had to be named with camelcase starting with a capital. So weird. Had to use `git mv` in order to get git to recognize the name change as well because it doesn't normally care about case.